# Toggle after clicking twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JAVASCRIPT function to change few things after clicking a shape called Hexagon, as you can see here:

JAVASCRIPT

```
$( ".hexagon1").on("click", function() {
  $( "#hex-area-2" ).css('display','block');
  $( "#hex-area-2" ).css('transition','display 1s ease-in');
  $( "#left-line-animated-container-left").css('display','block');
  $( "#left-line-animated-container-right").css('display','block');
  $( "#left-line-animated-container-center").css('display','block');
  $( "#hex-area-1").css('height','300px');
  $( "#hex-area-centralizer").css('height','300px');
});
```

On click, all that stuff changes, but what If I want to restore original values if I click again this Hexagon? there's a way to do it with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS classes for this. Assign the default CSS to the particular `id`'s and then toggle a class on the body and let the modified CSS properties cascade down to their appropriate elements:

```
/* Default CSS */
#hex-area-2 {
    ...
}
#left-line-animated-container-left {
    ...
}
#left-line-animated-container-right {
    ...
}
#left-line-animated-container-center {
    ...
}
#hex-area-1 {
    ...
}
#hex-area-centralizer {
    ...
}

/* CSS applied on click */
.hex1-toggle #hex-area-2 {
    display: block;
    transition: display 1s ease-in;
}
.hex1-toggle #left-line-animated-container-left,
.hex1-toggle #left-line-animated-container-right,
.hex1-toggle #left-line-animated-container-center {
    display: block;
}
.hex1-toggle #hex-area-1,
.hex1-toggle #hex-area-centralizer {
    height: 300px;
}

$( ".hexagon1").on("click", function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('hex1-toggle');
});
```

This *"cascading"* effect is the *"C"* in CSS. By toggling the one class on the body, the stylesheet will effectively cascade the resulting changes when the DOM redraw is triggered. Note that the `hex1-toggle` class in this case does not have to be at the `body` level. It could and probably should be at the closest parent, grandparent, etc. element to ***all*** of the elements that you're wanting to modify. It was placed at the `body` level in the case of this demo simply because no HTML structure was supplied in the question and I chose not to infer.

Comment: this really works! now I have to study what you did, thanks @War10ck

Comment: @Eugenio No problem. Happy to help. Let me know if any part doesn't make sense and I'll be happy to elaborate on it more.

Answer (score 1):

Make classes for all your CSS and then onclick just toggle those classes.

Eg:

```
.hex-area-2{
  display:block;
}

$( ".hexagon1").on("click", function() {
    $( "#hex-area-2" ).toggleClass("hex-area-2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could set up the functions similar to this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    $('.hexagon1').toggle(function() {
      $( "#hex-area-2" ).css('display','block');
      $( "#hex-area-2" ).css('transition','display 1s ease-in');
      $( "#left-line-animated-container-left").css('display','block');
      $( "#left-line-animated-container-right").css('display','block');
      $( "#left-line-animated-container-center").css('display','block');
      $( "#hex-area-1").css('height','300px');
      $( "#hex-area-centralizer").css('height','300px');
    }, function() {
      // second click stuff here
    });
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively to having all the actions in the function, you could just make a style for each toggle state and add/remove them as needed.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    $('.hexagon1').toggle(function() {
      $('hexagon1').addClass('className');
    }, function() {
      $('hexagon1').removeClass('className');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Heads up, the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method that was part of the event handling suite was deprecated in jq 1.8 and removed in jq 1.9...

Comment: @War10ck Great catch!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
$( ".hexagon1").on("click", function() {
  if(i === 1) {
    $( "#hex-area-2" ).css('display','block');
    $( "#hex-area-2" ).css('transition','display 1s ease-in');
    $( "#left-line-animated-container-left").css('display','block');
    $( "#left-line-animated-container-right").css('display','block');
    $( "#left-line-animated-container-center").css('display','block');
    $( "#hex-area-1").css('height','300px');
    $( "#hex-area-centralizer").css('height','300px');
  } else {
    $( "#hex-area-2" ).removeAttr('style');
    $( "#left-line-animated-container-left").removeAttr('style');
    $( "#left-line-animated-container-right").removeAttr('style');
    $( "#left-line-animated-container-center").removeAttr('style');
    $( "#hex-area-1").removeAttr('style');
    $( "#hex-area-centralizer").removeAttr('style');
  }
  $i++; // add 1 to i
  $i = ($i === 3) ? 1 : $i; // if i is now 3 reset to 1
});
```

`.removeAttr('style');` will remove inline styles on the elements.  If you have set styles in a CSS stylesheet, and then the jQuery above adds inline styles, as this removes the entire `style=""` attribute, it should reset all the styles back to what they were.

Comment: This is assuming that the OP does not already have default inline styles applied or that previous events and interactions on the page haven't altered the inline styles of these particular elements as well. Not necessarily a stretch to believe that could be true but definitely some assumptions to be aware of...

Comment: Yep, that's why I said about the CSS Stylesheet.  Will work, could do with refactoring without a doubt.